# How can I make a bash script display its output like `man`, not filling up the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

For example - run `man` in a terminal. I don't know how they did that - but it runs in a way that it doesn't output everything into the terminal - when you press <kbd>q</kbd> it goes away, and goes back to the terminal (and gives back all the output that we used before)

This is what I want in a nutshell:

```
$ ./myscript.sh
```

It turns into this:

```
Hello!
Please press q to make this go away!
```

After pressing <kbd>Q</kbd>:

```
$ ./myscript.sh
$
```

I know this is possible, i just don't get how it works. Does it have something to do with saving the output from before, and printing it back to the terminal after the termination of `myscript.sh`? If so, how? If not, also how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11023929/1030675

Comment: Put this as a answer so i can tick it please.

Comment: Can someone explain why this is being closed as off-topic? It seems like an ordinary bash scripting question we've seen 10's of thousands of posted here in **Ask Ubuntu**.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Hit "leave open" [here](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/867187) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11024208), you can toggle the screen using `tput smcup` and `tput rmcup` and just wrap it in while loop like so:

```
tput smcup


#Do stuff here


echo "Press Q to quit"
while true
do 
  read -n 1 -s
  if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Qq]$ ]]
  then
    tput rmcup
  fi
done
```